# How to deploy and distribute ios flutter app among friends (not app store)

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter, deployment

Hi so I made a basic flutter app on android studio on my windows system. How can I set it up so that my friend can download the app from a link and just keep it on her phone and open it whenever on her IOS device? I do have access to a Mac but no developer account. What's the easiest way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no easy way for this.

For the "easiest" way to share an iPhone-build you need to build from a Mac itself (via XCode). You can upload and share internal builds of your app for download via Testflight, but that does require a developer-license.

Yes, there *are* alternatives, like building via a server and automating uploads, but those require considerably more knowledge, time & other tools to accomplish.